# JComboBox currently selected item background and Windows LaF

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox, look-and-feel

I could do not find other way then:

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.background",new Color(31,0,104));
UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground",new Color(31,0,104));
```

to set backgorund colour of currently selected item in JComboBox.
Unfortunatelly this will work same for all comboboxes in window which I do not want.

This is how it currently works:
[PICTURE](http://s11.postimg.org/9eu7lel0j/current_Problem.png)

This is how I want it to behave:
[PICTURE](http://s27.postimg.org/kiiim2mn7/how_Iwantit.png)

I tried creating custom DefaultListCellRenderer and call setBackground there , but it did not help. I also tried overriding BasicComboBoxUI ,but I probably do not which method I should override to achieve result.

EDIT:
This is short part of my code according to suggestion ,but it did not help

```
public void colorizeComboBox(){
 
     jComboBox1.setRenderer(new ColourListCellRenderer());
    jComboBox1.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI(){
        @Override 
        protected JButton createArrowButton() {
            JButton b = this.createCustomArrowButton();
            b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            b.setBackground(new Color(31,0,104));
            b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            return b;
         }
        
    
        public JButton createCustomArrowButton() {
              JButton b=new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/server/Pictures/arrowdown.png")));
              b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
              b.setOpaque(true);
              return b;
        }
    });
```

and custom renderer:

```
  public static  class ColourListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
     
    
     @Override
    public Color getBackground() {
       return new Color(31,0,104);
     }

  
}
```

but all this changed now is that background of currently selected item is WHITE.

Comment: Please explain what you want. Do you want to make the selected row looks like unselected ones?

Comment: When called, the `ListCellRenderer` is passed `-1` (I think) for the item `index` value when it renders the "selected" value.  You could try performing some special rendering when this occurs...

Comment: I tried your code but it does not color anything.

Answer (score 0):

Override DefaultListCellRenderer's getBackground and getListCellRendererComponent method.

```
public class ColoredListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private Color selectedColor;
    private Color backgroundColor;
    private Color lastColor;

    public ColoredListCellRenderer(Color backgroundColor, Color selectedColor) {
        this.selectedColor = selectedColor;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        lastColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (isSelected) {
            lastColor = selectedColor;
        } else {
            lastColor = backgroundColor;
        }
        c.setBackground(lastColor);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBackground() {
        return lastColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution ,but it seems that it just change background of selected item to white. Seem my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Answer by OP moved from question to an answer:

> ***Ok finally found solution:***
>
> ```
>  jComboBox1.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI(){
>        
>         
>         @Override
>         public void paintCurrentValueBackground(Graphics g,Rectangle bounds,boolean hasFocus){
>             
>              Color t = g.getColor();
>             if ( comboBox.isEnabled() )
>                 g.setColor(new Color(31,0,104));
>             else
>                 g.setColor(DefaultLookup.getColor(comboBox, this,
>                                          "ComboBox.disabledBackground", null));
>             g.fillRect(bounds.x,bounds.y,bounds.width,bounds.height);
>             g.setColor(t);
>         }
>         
>     
>         
>         
>         
>         
>     });
>      jComboBox1.setFocusable(false);
> ```
>
> I had to override paintCurrentValueBackground(..) in BasicComboBoxUI
> ,then set this UI to combo box ,but focus was still making problem and
> painting combo boxx to grey so I disabled focus on this combobox